# Bash: numbered files in Find

Tags: linux, bash, find

I was writing a bash script that finds and deletes the .blend1 and .blend2 files that blender creates as you edit and save .blend files.  It contains lines in pairs like this:

```
find Documents -name "*.blend1" -exec rm -rf {} \;
find Documents -name "*.blend2" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This works just fine, though I was curious if it is at all possible to combine those two find commands some way, so that it would be just one command that finds and deletes both .blend1 and .blend2 files.

Not super-important, I'd just prefer it if my script were a little more compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find Documents -name '*.blend[12]' -delete
```

(`-delete` is a GNU find extension.)

Other ways:

```
find Documents '(' -name '*.blend1' -o -name '*.blend2' ')' -delete
find Documents -name '*.blend*' -delete
```

Comment: All good answers, though I chose this one because it's the simplest.  A word of warning though: the second of the two alternate commands you listed is NOT a good idea because it will also delete the unnumbered .blend files, which would effectively delete my blender projects

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way...

```
find Documents -name '*.blend[12]' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use regex to match more that one patterns into one:

```
find Documents -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*\.(blend1|blend2)$' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Or with newer `find` versions:

```
find Documents -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*\.(blend1|blend2)$' -delete
```

Without regex you can do:

```
find Documents \( -name "*.blend1" -o -name "*.blend2" \) -delete
```